# How can I remove the youtube video controls using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm working on an extension and I need help to remove the video controls and replace it with the native browser controls.
This is what I have

```
document.getElementById("(*YOUTUBE CONTROLS*)").innerHTML = "<video controls>"
```

Comment: There's no direct way to switch to custom browser controls unless you're using a ```<video>``` tag. But you can most certainly edit the Youtube player styles through CSS. Just inspect element and go look at the styles. You can edit them as required. You don't need JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide youtube controls with ?controls=0 after src
ex:

and some [more customization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

To reskins the player you can write a custom jquery of js function to edit the content of the frame after it's loaded.

Here's and [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/a7r9L/)

**HTML**

```
<iframe width="800" scrolling="no" id="prev" src="">your browser needs to be updated.
</iframe>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#prev').contents().find('body').html('<div> blah </div>');
})
```